# Google Spreadsheet: SQL query for automatic update

Tags: sql, google-sheets

Suppose I have one master sheet with several columns and rows which keeps updating whenever. Now I need to use some of the data from the master sheet as reference, to create analytic report in another sheet. How can I use a SQL query to reference the appropriate data from the original sheet? And by doing so, what happens when the original sheet is updated with more records? Will they be automatically included as well in the second sheet?

I'm just a beginner, but if anyone has any clue in this matter, or if there's any alternative method that could be implemented, please let me know! I'd be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [Google Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage).

> The QUERY function is a built-in function that allows you to perform a query over an array of values using the Google Visualization API Query Language.
>
> Query String - A query string for applying data operations. The query operates on column IDs directly from the input range and uses a subset of the SQL language. For example, "select E," "select A , B," "sum(B),C group by C," "select D where D < 'Nick' ."

[Documentation](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1388882)

Comment: Would the query also update and include any new records that may be added to the original sheet the next time? i.e. In the case where the original master sheet keeps updating weekly, would the updated rows be included in the query as well?

Comment: I would imagine that your QUERY pulls real-time data.